# Installing clearcase 6 and 7 version on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I want to know anybody have tried installing clearcase 6 , 7 version on windows 7 OS.

Thanks ,

Comment: At the same time, on the same machine?  Or independently on different machines?  Why would you want to use ClearCase 6, anyway?

Comment: I have edited my answer to propose an alternative, allowing a ClearCase installation in a VM (Windows Xp) on your Windows 7 workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 is only supported for ClearCase 7.2+ ([actually, 7.1.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974#windows)+ but it has some issues, especially with 64 bits).

See:

- "[Rational Clearcase Explorer has stopped working bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087016/rational-clearcase-explorer-has-stopped-working-bug/13087947#13087947)"
- "[System Requirements for ClearCase 7.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974#windows)"

The "[System Requirements for ClearCase 2003.06.xx](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21136950#Table1)" doesn't mention Widows 7.
You cannot install a ClearCase on a Windows 7.

---

As I mention in "[Clearcase on windows 7 can not create dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454303/clearcase-on-windows-7-can-not-create-dynamic-view/13454644#13454644)":

> You can try and install a **[Virtual PC Windows Xp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd796757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** on your Windows 7.

With a Windows Xp, you can install any ClearCase 6 or 7 you need.